# How to add a library that has no Jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jwt

I'm attempting to include a new library in my project, however I believe I am incorrectly adding the library to the project as I'll still receive errors that the packages cannot be found.

I believe the cause of this is that I'm not actually adding a Jar to my project, since the source files, [JWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt), lack one.

Using Netbeans 8.1, and the application I'm trying to include JWT in is an ordinary Java Web Application.

Comment: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cio.jsonwebtoken there is a jar.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks a lot bud.

Comment: I should really start posting those tiny answering comments as actual answers ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the maven dependency is given on intro page itself

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
<artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
<version>0.7.0</version>
```

UPDATE-

well in that case use

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt

Comment: I'm unable to use Maven for this project, that's the tricky part, and why I need the JAR.

Comment: @Andrew "Unable" why? Maven or Gradle is almost *always* the answer.